# Bell State, if Bob applies a Pauli Gate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

After Alice and Bob share a Bell state, Bob applies a Pauli gate to his qubit. What will be the situation of the Bell state? What happens?

Then Alice applies the same gate to her qubit – again, what happens?

I would be thankful if you could explain it slowly, as I am a beginner in this field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pauli gates applied to one qubit will just transform one Bell state into another one. Take, for example, the antisymmetric singlet state:
$$|\psi_{AB}^-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow_A\rangle\otimes|\downarrow_B\rangle - |\downarrow_A\rangle\otimes|\uparrow_B\rangle). $$
Alice applies the Pauli X gate, defined as $\sigma^x|\uparrow\rangle = |\downarrow\rangle$, $\sigma^x|\downarrow\rangle = |\uparrow\rangle$. The gate is local, so it acts as the identity on Bob's qubit (it does nothing to Bob's qubit). This is written as
\begin{eqnarray}(\sigma^x_A\otimes 1_B) |\psi_{AB}^-\rangle &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\sigma^x_A|\uparrow_A\rangle\otimes 1_B|\downarrow_B\rangle - \sigma^x_A|\downarrow_A\rangle\otimes 1_B|\uparrow_B\rangle) \\ &=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\downarrow_A\rangle\otimes|\downarrow_B\rangle - |\uparrow_A\rangle\otimes|\uparrow_B\rangle) \\ &=& |\phi_{AB}^-\rangle,\end{eqnarray}
which is just a different Bell state. This demonstrates the *local unitary equivalence* of Bell states.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that means if apply any Pauli to a qubit of bell state, it will only affect the local qubit but not the other, right ?

Comment: if you apply *any* unitary to just one qubit (this is called a local unitary operation), it doesn't affect the other.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you were also wondering what would happen if *both* Alice and Bob apply the same Pauli gate on their respective qubit. To complement Mark's answer, I would like to expand on this point. Interestingly, the answer is that nothing happens, the action of their individual gates is equivalent to the identity map! This is a consequence of the more general result that for any maximally entangled pure state $|\psi\rangle$ and any unitary $U$, it holds that
$$U\otimes U^T|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle$$
where $U^T$ is just the transpose of $U$. All the Bell states are maximally entangled and the Pauli operators satisfy $\sigma_x^T=\sigma_x$, $\sigma_y^T=-\sigma_y$, $\sigma_z^T=\sigma_z$ so that if both Alice and Bob apply the same Pauli gate, from the above result the state is unchanged (up to a global phase).

Comment: Nice, I noticed this when I was writing my answer, but didn't know why it seemed to be true for all the examples I could think of. Does this hold for arbitrary dimensions?

Comment: It does work in arbitrary dimensions.  Specifically, let $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_i |i\rangle \otimes |i\rangle$ and let $U$ be any unitary.  Then $U \otimes U^* |\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$ where the star denotes complex conjugate.

Comment: Are you sure it's a complex conjugate and not a transpose?

Comment: @JuanMiguelArrazola Yes, what you wrote is wrong. It should be complex conjugate.